# gSOAP multithreaded server crashes when trying to deallocate memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, gsoap

I have created a standalone multithreaded webservice using gSOAP framework but this code has memory leak and when i try to deallocte that memory it crashes after sometime.

Below is the detailed steps i have followed for creating webservice.

1. soapcpp2 -i -S -I Services.h
2. compiled the code by adding the generated files and stdsoap.h/cpp files in visual studio.

Below is the code where i am spawning whenever i receive a new request.

```
struct Services
{
    
        abcService* aServver;
        defService* dServer;
        ghiService* gServer;
        jklService* jServer;
}

DWORD WINAPI StartThread(void* lparam)`
{
        
        Services *sp = static_cast<Services*>(lparam);

        if(soap_begin_serve(sp->aServer->soap)){
            soap_send_fault(sp->aServer);
        }
        else if(sp->aServer->dispatch() == SOAP_NO_METHOD)
        {
            soap_copy_stream(sp->dServer,sp->aServer);
            soap_free_stream(sp->aServer);
            if(sp->dServer->dispatch() == SOAP_NO_METHOD)
            {
                soap_copy_stream(sp->gServer,sp->dServer);
                soap_free_stream(sp->dServer);
                if(sp->gServer->dispatch() == SOAP_NO_METHOD)
                {
                    soap_copy_stream(sp->jServer,sp->gServer);
                    soap_free_stream(sp->gServer);

                    if(sp->jServer->dispatch())
                    {
                        soap_send_fault(sp->jServer);
                    }
                   sp->jServer->destroy();
                }
            sp->gServer->destroy();
         }
        sp->dServer->destroy();
    }
    sp->aServer->destroy();
    delete(sp->aServer);    //--->Line 48
    delete(sp->dSever);     //--->Line 49
    delete(sp->gServer);    //--->Line 50
    delete(sp->jServer);    //--->Line 51
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    abcService aServver;
    defService dServer;
    ghiService gServer;
    jklService jServer;

    aServer.bind(NULL,8090,100);
    Services servv;
    for(;;)
    {
            aServer.accept();

            
            servv.aServver = aServer.copy();   //--->Line no 21
            servv.dServer = dServer.copy();    //--->Line no 22
            servv.gServer = gServer.copy();    //--->Line no 23
            servv.jServer = jServer.copy();    //--->Line no 24

            DWORD Threadid;
            HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL,0,StartThread,(void*)&servv,0,&Threadid);
            CloseHandle(handle);
     }
}
```

Memory is created starting from line no 21 to Line 24 and these objects are passed to thread spawned on each request.

Once the request is processed in the spawned thread, then i try to delete these objects starting at line no 48.
After sometime , it starts crashing randomly at line no 48. This issue is reproducible.

I am not sure what is causing this issue , can anybody help me here ?

Comment: it only crushes at `delete(sp->aServer);`? or if you change the order it still crush at line 48?

Comment: @yaodav Yes ..even if i change the sequence of deletion of objects, it still crashes at line 48, means the first object i am trying to delete.

Comment: I don't use gsoap, so this question might be worthless, but... In your main, you create Services servv and that gets passed into CreateThread. How sure are you that StartThread completes before CreateThread returns? It seems to me that if this is multi-threading, servv could be garbage sometime during StartThread's execution.

Comment: @JosephLarson -- servv is just holding the pointers of objects created through copy method and that address thats gets passed to StartThread. So it will not make any difference .. Anyways i have tried creating the servv object outside for loop as well but it didn't help.

Comment: You pass the address of servv, but if this is multithreaded, that address may no longer be valid and could contain random garbage.

Comment: Understood your point but i have checked by creating servv outside for loop. I have edited the question accordingly. so it does not create confusion further

Comment: @spn If one request comes in while the previous hasn't finished, you overwrite the `servv` pointers and can (and will) have double deletions.

Comment: @spn if it crashes at the first delete so I think your problem that is not valid anymore - do print on the thread and see if it still printing when you try to delete it

Comment: double deletion i doubt .. as when first request comes object will be allocated using copy method and address will be passed to different thread ..by then if second request comes servv will have pointers of the newly object created by copy methods...so ultimately it will be Starthhread which will be adeallocating objects created by copy methods.